# How to execute gradle task during project import in Intellij Idea

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Let's assume my `build.gradle` file contains task `generateSources` which as name suggests generates additional java files. It's easy to ensure that `generateSources` is executed before `compileJava`: `compileJava.dependsOn generateSources`. How can I make sure `generateSources` is called when importing project into Intellij Idea as well?

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on @vladimir-sitnikov's answer: I added the [`idea-ext`](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin)-plugin to my root project:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext'

// ...

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext:org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext.gradle.plugin:0.7"
  }
}
```

Because without that I wasn't able to use it in my sub project, but now it works like this:

```
idea.project.settings.taskTriggers {
  beforeSync tasks.getByName("generateSources")
}
```

Adding the plugin to the sub-project only didn't do it.

Note: The plugin's documentation is kind of limited, but in "[DSL spec v. 0.2](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/DSL-spec-v.-0.2#gradle-tasks-triggers-settings)" is stated

> - `beforeSync` - before each Gradle project sync. **Will NOT be executed on initial import**

Didn't try that, but it works with existing projects.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via `id("org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext")` plugin (https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin).

See sample code in Gradle sources: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/135fb4751faf2736c231636e8a2a92d47706a3b9/buildSrc/subprojects/ide/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/gradlebuild/ide/IdePlugin.kt#L147

Answer (score 1):

You can set the task in Gradle tool window: *Execute Before Sync*:

[image]

Comment: I wasn't specific enough: I'd like to include that information ("execute `generateSources` before sync) in `build.gradle`. Do you know how to do this? Even if no: thanks for showing that in UI!